# Weed Identification

Tags: identification, seedlings, weeds, mulch, onions

I found this weed in my veggie patch and I was wondering if anyone could identify it and maybe provide some information about it.

### Key Information

- Canberra, Australia.
- Only seen in the last day.
- Garden only started 2 weeks ago.
- Garden mulched 3 days ago. (Maybe I should have weeded more thoroughly before mulching... :(  )
- Roots look a bit like an onion. Most of them have been torn off though.
- Growing in the garden currently is Spinach, Spring Onion and Basil.

[image: Weed picture]

Answer (score 8):

I planted some [Oxalis deppei](http://tropical.theferns.info/viewtropical.php?id=Oxalis+deppei) in the garden at my university last year and it looked just like your plant. It had little dark pink flowers and spread like crazy, from 15 bulbs planted in spring I got at least 50 bulbs in autumn, including smaller ones. This was on a rocky small area that somewhat contained them.

Comment: Maybe that. Looking into it. I think there might be some somewhere else in my yard...